# AWS Cloudwatch custom action

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Does anyone know if it is possible to create an Action in Cloudwatch to perform and application pool recycle on an instance if the thread count gets too high?  An example would also be helpful.

Thanks,

Rhonda

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create a custom CloudWatch metric for number of threads. Upon an alarm, that would [publish to an SNS topic](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html) which would [trigger](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html#supported-event-source-sns) a Lambda function to be run. The Lambda function can do whatever you need it to.